# How to create boiler plate for any k8s object

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to create boiler plate for any k8s object.

For instance, the `deployment` object boilerplate can be generated by using `kubectl`:

`kubectl run --dry-run -o yaml ...`

This will generate the yaml configuration file of the deployment object. I can redirect this to a file and modify the fields I need.

But how about objects other than deployment? What about CronJob? Are there any ways to generate boilerplate config file for CronJob object (or any other k8s object at that matter)?

Answer (score 3):

While `kubectl create object-type -o yaml` will give you the very basics, it doesn't normally cover much of the spec.

Instead, I prefer to fetch existing objects and modify:

`kubectl get configmap configMapName -o yaml > configmap.yaml`

Strip away everything you don't need, including generated fields; and you're good to go. This step probably requires a solid understanding of what to expect in each YAML.

EDIT://

I just realised there's `--export` when using this approach that strips generated fields for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, these approaches don't work for me because 1/ `kubectl create` doesn't support all objects (cronjob for example). Even for some objects that it supports like deployment, you have to specify required tag like image for it to generate a boilerplate config file. I don't want to go through all that hassle. I want something like `kubectl gen-boilerplate deployment` and have the boilerplate with all/common fields with boilerplate value. 2/ What if the type of object I want to create has never been created in my cluster yet?

Comment: There is no way to do that then. Sadly, this is as good as it gets for now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no defacto standard of "base" templates to use. I am actually working on a site to curb this problem (https://k8specs.com).

What I would recommend doing is slowing accumulating your kubernetes objects like I have (see: https://github.com/mateothegreat?tab=repositories&q=k8-byexamples -- look in my manifests directories throughout the repo's) where I can use `envsubst` to then update the values I want to "template" using simple environment variables.

The kubernetes.io documentation has a plethora of documentation with line-by-line examples of each object definition that there is, I would recommend starting there.

If you're looking for anything specific just mention what you need and we will help you drafting your spec's!

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised that there's no official way to generate a boilerplate config yet. I was thinking maybe the professionals have some niche way to do this and it was because I'm newbie to this I get stuck. I looked through your site (https://k8specs.com) and it seems like what I need (k8s object config boilerplates). Hope you'll get that up and working soon!

Answer (score 0):

You can create other objects than deployment using kubectl run, but you have to specify the generator or restart flag. You can find more informations about it here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators.

Regarding objects other than those available via kubectl run you can use kubectl create to see kind of objects you can create.